# Python: Print entire line of string match and not cut off after the period

Tags: python-3.x

See bottom for the solution I came up with.

Hopefully this is a easy question for you guys. Trying to match a string to a list and print just that string matched. I was successful using re, but it is cutting off the rest of the string after the period. The span per re is 0,10 and when i look at the output without using re it is 0,14 not 0,10 so match is cutting off the info after the period. So I would like to learn how to tell it to print the entire span or learn a new way to match a var string to a list and print that exact string. My original attempts printed anything with the TESTPR in it, 3 printed total, the others I do not want printing have a 1 in the front and the last match has an additional R at the end. Here is my current match code:

```
#OLD See below
for element in catalog:
    z = re.match("((TESTPRR )\w+)", element)
    if z:
        print((z.group()))

Output: TESTPR 105
```

It should show:

```
Wanted output: TESTPT 105.465
```

It will go up to 3 decimal places after the period and no more. I am currently taking a Python class to learn Python and love it so far, but this one has me stumped as I am just now learning about re and matching by reading as we have not gotten to that yet in class.

I am open to learning a different way to search for and match a string and print just that string. For my first attempt that prints 3 results was this:

```
catalog = [ long list pulled from API then code here to make it a nice column]
prod = 'TESTPR'
print ([s for s in catalog if prod in s])
```

When I add a space at the end of prod i can get rid of the match with the extra char at the end, but I cannot add a space to do the same thing with the match that has an extra char at the front. This is for the code above and not for the re match code. Thanks!

Answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kept at it with re.match and got the correct regex so the entire match prints and it does not cut off numbers after the period.

my original match as you can see above was re.match("((TESTPRR )\w+)", element), some of the ( were unneeded and needed to add a few more expressions and now it prints the correct match. See above for old code and below for the new code that works.

```
# New code, replaced w+ with w*\d*[.,]?\d*$
for element in catalog:
    z = re.match("STRING\w*\d*[.,]?\d*$", element)
    if z:
        print(z.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in learning about ways to match strings and solve your problem: try [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/0.3.0/).

In your case you could try:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

catalog = [long list pulled from API then code here to make it a nice column]
prod = "TESTPR"
hit = process.extractOne(prod, catalog, score_cutoff = 75) #you can adjust this to suit how close the match should be
print(hit[0]) #hit will be sth like ("TESTPT 105.465", 75)

Output: TESTPT 105.465
```

For information on different ways of using fuzzywuzzy, check out [this link](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/).

You can use different ways of matching such as:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio
fuzz.ratio
token_sort_ratio
fuzz.token_set_ratio
```

for this from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

Comment: so i had to use import fuzz, still working on my code, when trying to install fuzzywuzzy i got: Collecting fuzzwuzzy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fuzzwuzzy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fuzzwuzzy

Comment: get the same error with process, sorry I should have added my env, python 3.7 Windows 10

Comment: sorry it may work, but i cannot get fuzzywuzzy to install via pip on my version and on windows, i will look into a manual install

Comment: kept at it with re.match and got the regex right, posting my new code in my OP